# Confused about the way robocopy works

Tags: windows, powershell, robocopy

I am little confused about the way robocopy works.
I have a file on a network drive under for example **\myserver\shared\dir1** which is 150 MB.
I have a powershell script that check **\myserver\shared\dir2** (dir2, not dir1) every min. If file exist in there, it will copy it to the same local computer under c:\mydir\files
So a user on some other computer will copy the file from \myserver\shared\dir1 folder and paste it into \myserver\shared\dir2 folder.
The user will get a little dialog/info windows which tells him it will take 4 mins for copy to get completed. The reason for 4 mins is the user is on a slower network and through VPN, so the copy process is slower for him.
A min later through task scheduler, the powershell is called which will see a file under \myserver\shared\dir2 and copy that with robocopy to the local computer under c:\mydir\files. This copy process is very fast because of the network zone and local area, so it will take like 30 secs.
While user who initiate the copy still sees over 2 mins for copy to get completed, the robocopy already copied the file to  c:\mydir\files and the size is 150 MB.
How is that possible? How can robocopy copy the 150 MB file while the user who initiated the copy still has over 2 mins to go?

Comment: Possibly explorer just pre-allocate whole file.

Comment: I don't this is a PowerShell, scripting or coding question at all. It should probably be moved to SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

**My theory.** 
If a file is copied to the Fileshare, the OS will pre-allocate the whole file with the correct extension while copying. 
With that in mind, testing the path with Powershell (probably using the test-path cmdlet) will return True, even if the whole file isn't copied to the fileshare yet.
Robocopy will then start copy the unfinnished file from your fileshare to the local computer.